# Remembering the value of a option box

Tags: php

The following code produces a dynamic dropdown box.

```
<select name="parent">
    <?php 
    $q = $admindb->getParentCategories();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
        $title=$row['title'];
        $catid=$row['id'];
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $catid; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></option>
        <?php
    }   
    ?>
</select>
```

However, if the form is returned to the user with validation errors,
I need the box to remember the previous selection..

When using a text box, I have used the following code to remember the entry..

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $form->value("title"); ?>">
```

How would I add what is in that value tag to the select code?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on exactly how it works when you say "returned to the user with validation errors". What kind of 'return' are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `option` line to:

```
<option value="<?php echo $catid; ?>"<?php if($catid == $form->value("fieldname") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $title; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `selected` attribute:

```
    <option value="<?php echo $catid; ?>"
        <?php if ($_GET['parent'] === $catid): echo 'selected'?>><?php echo $title; ?></option>
```

If you write XHTML, use `selected="selected"`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `selected="true"` to the correct option like this:

```
<select name="parent">
    <?php 
    $q = $admindb->getParentCategories();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
        $title=$row['title'];
        $catid=$row['id'];
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $catid; ?>" <?php if ($catid == $form->value("title")) { echo ' selected="true"';} ?>><?php echo $title; ?></option>
        <?php
    }   
    ?>
</select>
```